# Sitecore Send Sandbox not triggering email

Tags: moosend

We are using Sitecore Send sandbox. Is there any known limitation for sending emails using Sitecore Send sandbox?

We have an email automation for triggering emails but it doesn't work after triggering a few emails.

I tried triggering manual automation but emails were still not received. Earlier, it used to work as expected.

Comment: Manoj, Sitecore Send temporarily blocks suspicious accounts and disables sending. Check this - https://doc.sitecore.com/send/en/users/sitecore-send/blocking-accounts-with-high-bounce-and-complaint-rates.html